# What picture should the chat error page have?

Tags: discussion, chat, images, 500-server-error

Besides that fact that [chat's error page](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/error) is ugly because it has no styling, it also <s>steals</s> borrows the error lolcat image from Stack Overflow.

Of course we hope that nobody ever sees that page, but I'm sure we agree that's not going to happen, so we could at least have our own image.

So, what picture should the chat error page have?

<sub>You can go to `yourfavorite.stackexchange.com/error` for inspiration.</sub>

Comment: I'd go with "An image of balpha and Marc Gravell, the main minds behind chat, duking it out in fisticuffs as neither can determine who *actually* is at fault for the error.", but that's a bit too meta for an error image. But that's always my first instinct when there's an error.

Comment: A large version of Michael Mrozeks' "Chess Piece" with the flashing eyes.

Comment: @Grace - not true; we fully 100% agree on who is to blame.... *the other one*. And if that isn't enough, we just blame LINQ-to-SQL.

Comment: @GraceNote: I like that, actually.

Comment: @MarcGravell: You're wrong.

Answer (score 31):

Embed the [wheel of blame](http://jsfiddle.net/badp/zmV5w/37/embedded/result/) on the page so we know whose fault it is (some minor adjustments to the blame list might be in order).

[image: Example spin]

Comment: I see that's the improved version.

Comment: That wheel is broken.

Comment: I feel I would get banished if I flag that as [offensive] q: ~ How could you say such a thing about the wheel!

Comment: Well, if the wheel is on an error page, the wheel should also be erroneous. Mix matching gravatars with names would be an excellent start. Then again, the error page might become more popular than the service it embarrasses.

Comment: Makes me think of [this Dilbert comic](http://www.hutter1.net/private/random.gif).

Answer (score 28):

Instead of a picture it should just be a chat page where you can chat with all the other people who are getting errors right now.

Comment: or, something similar to the screen when chat was having the SSD upgrade? Chat Gold/Chat Premium?

Comment: Probably not what we're going with, but the idea is awesome. Have a bounty :)

Answer (score 17):

If someone with better skillz than I could Photoshop Jeff and Joel into this...

[image]

(Or Marc and Ben might work.)

Comment: While we're on the subject, what episode (if any) is the ["room not available" image](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/-1) from?

Comment: @mmyers: I'm deferring that question to the real experts. [Which episode of Star Trek: TNG is this image from?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/4159/which-episode-of-star-trek-tng-is-this-image-from)

Comment: @BillTheLizard [Flag for migration]

Comment: Why photoshop them in? Spend some of that VC mula on some ST shirts and just have them pose for this photo the same way!

Comment: Considering the double facepalm [is photoshopped](http://au.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100205102659AAkT72S) (yes, that's Y! Answers), I'd say not to try too hard for authenticity.

Comment: [Done](http://so.mrozekma.com/photoshop-master.png)

Comment: @MichaelMrozek: That actually says "FAIL" better than the original.

Comment: there is a de-facto star trek theme on chat, is there not? http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/404

Comment: @mmyers: Wow, that's actually the first very good question/answer pair I see on Y! Answers. No kidding!

Answer (score 13):

Along the same lines as the lolcat image from Stack Overflow, for consistency reasons:

[image: Profesionl lolcats]

Answer (score 12):

[image]

Or even better.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image: Chat Fail]

Comment: This looks like Anthony Weiner with a slightly rounder face.

Comment: Uh, what is this?

Comment: @Cody ...it's from The Matrix.

Answer (score -2):

[image: hopefully no infrigment]

Comment: I understand downvotes for others, but why da hell for me and Ham and Bacon?!

Answer (score -2):

[image: Even Ph.D.s have trouble operating microwave.]

Answer (score -3):

You should put community promotion ads in the error page. It'll server to further alienate users and confuse people when clicking the error image takes them to, I dunno, somewhere else.

Answer (score -3):

in keeping with the (picard) facepalm...
[image]

Comment: *chuckle* so, maybe not then.

Answer (score -3):

My two coins:

[image]

or maybe:

[image]

How about:

[image]

[image]