# System message indicating badge was awarded was not displayed

Tags: support, status-completed, badges, system-message

I was awarded the Deputy and Strunk & White badges today.

[image: yAyy badge!]

But in both the cases, the system message announcing

> You have been awarded <> badge

was not displayed. Why is this so?

Comment: While the reputation tab begs _read me, read me_ to no avail.

Comment: @RickSladkey hehe :)

Comment: Voting to close because this style of system message no longer exists.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I incorrectly marked this [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign); but I was wrong - the "veteran" badge code is only supposed to apply to ***bronze*** badges. This is being corrected.

Good spot.

Comment: I wasn't get notified of a bronze tag badge the other day. Was that due to this? Seems like tag badge notifications should be shown regardless of level, if that's the case.

Comment: @Tim if you are a multi-site veteran, a number (not all) of the bronze badges are deliberately not notified. If you feel one was suppressed that should be shown, please indicate which.

Comment: I didn't see a notification when I received the [bronze `[support]`](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/80/support?userid=150235) badge the other day.

Comment: @Tim actually it seems that the fix I applied above also means that bronze tag badges now get notified again. Better?

Comment: Brilliant, thanks! +1 to your comment-ninja skills as well. ;)

Answer (score 7):

The number of system messages (including badge awards) have been reduced for experienced users.

[Prevent the 'Notification Fiesta'](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96951/prevent-the-notification-bar-fiesta/96955#96955)

Comment: It seems strange to me that this means Sathya doesn't get notified of silver badges, but I still see the notification bar for earning bronze "Nice Answer" badges. (It just happened today, so I'm not thinking of a time before this went into effect.) I'd assume I qualify as an "experienced user" here.

Comment: @Cody it is not just strange; it was wrong; see update

Comment: @cody I SPIN MY WHEEL OF BLAME! A winner every time... http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95110/what-picture-should-the-chat-error-page-have/95111#95111

Comment: I hadn't known about the behavior as mentioned the linked question, thanks