# Why was I not notified for earning a bronze badge, even the first time?

Tags: discussion, badges, notifications, notification-bar

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Prevent the 'Notification Bar Fiesta'](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96951/prevent-the-notification-bar-fiesta)
>   [System message indicating badge was awarded was not displayed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99082/system-message-indicating-badge-was-awarded-was-not-displayed)

I used to get notified for my earned badges, now I don't.
I think that notification was a good thing and I think we should get notified for earning badges, at least for the first time of earning that badge.

If people are disturbed by the badge notification bar which comes out on the top of the page, we can just get it in our inboxes.

Can't we?

**EDIT:** For bronze badges.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prevent the 'Notification Bar Fiesta'](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96951/prevent-the-notification-bar-fiesta), also see Marc's answer [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99082/system-message-indicating-badge-was-awarded-was-not-displayed/99087#99087) explaining that this will apply to bronze badges only.

Comment: Marc's answer [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99082/system-message-indicating-badge-was-awarded-was-not-displayed/99087#99087) is the key issue. *(Adding this so the link doesn't disappear if the question gets closed)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are being notified only about silver or gold badges. When I earned silver badge yesterday, I was noticed about that. I think it isn't necessary in case of bronze badges

You can see today badges [image] here

Comment: Well, if everybody thinks this way I don't have anything to say.However, I think new comers may not think like that or those who hasn't earned all the bronze badges yet.

Comment: @JohnnyCageWins: You're not newcommer. I am pretty sure I was being noticed about every badge when I was newcommer. It's maybe based on reputation. Can you imagine how would [Jon Skeet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6787183/super-statement-in-c/6787199#6787199) like if he would get noticed for each badge?

Comment: This is correct. "Veteran" users (those that have been around for a while and are assumed to know how the site works) are [no longer being notified](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96951/prevent-the-notification-bar-fiesta) of bronze badges earned in order to keep down the noise. The fiesta has ended. (They [will still be notified](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99082/system-message-indicating-badge-was-awarded-was-not-displayed/99087#99087) of silver and gold badges, and new users are still invited to the fiesta.)

Comment: Well, thanks.Jon Skeet example was already in my mind but I still think if a user earned a badge for the first time, it would be nice to he/she gets notified.

Comment: @JohnnyCageWins: It's not as if you cannot find out, but merely that the invasive notification bar at the top of the page is suppressed. If you hover over your account name, all the badges you've earned today are displayed in the drop-down, at the bottom.

Comment: @JohnnyCageWins: answer edited. Cody: Thank you for idea

Comment: ok, that is nice thank you Gray, thank you genesis.

Comment: Excellent; would have edited the answer and included this, but I haven't earned any badges today! :-(

Comment: @Cody - to be exact, *some* bronze badges are suppressed. Not all.

Answer (score 3):

I've earned the bronze badge, and was notified about that.
However, some time ago, when I've earned another bronze badge, I've no notification about this.
The only difference between this two badges (for me) is the page I've started the day on the site. If I started with frontpage - I got the notification, and if I started with my profile page - I've got nothing.