# No notification for some badge awards

Tags: bug, badges, notification-bar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why was I not notified for earning a bronze badge, even the first time?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99404/why-was-i-not-notified-for-earning-a-bronze-badge-even-the-first-time)

I'm doing a bit of badge hunting, and have got the Analytical and Excavator badges in SO. However I didn't get the notification-bar stating that they had been awarded - my Bronze badge number just incremented.

However when I got the Quorum badge I did get the notification-bar.

I'm using an up-to-date installation of Chrome if that's relevant.

Comment: It's by design, not a bug - see linked question. From what I see all the "first time [something]" or trivial badges that requires just navigating to some links are suppressed, while badges that requires some more effort are still shown, even if only bronze..

Comment: Fair enough - I like the idea of the "notification fiesta"!. How can I mark this as closed?

Comment: Just add your vote to the close as duplicate if you can, and hopefully others will see this soon and it will get closed.

Comment: I'm too junior on meta to get those vote rights. Maybe meta should allow people more rights where they've got decent rep in one of the other sites. Can feel a feature request coming on.

Comment: You should be able to close your own question - just checked in other site where I have low reputation.. just click the "close" link below the question tags. :)

Comment: You need 250 rep even for your own questions, @ShadowWizard.

Comment: @PopularDemand dang, I checked in [gaming](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/) where I have ~500