# Missing badge notifications for badges earned on other sites?

Tags: support, badges

Some times I notice I have a new badge by the number in the header, but there is no notification 'You've earned X badge, see it in your profile'. Over time I got the impression, that this happens only for badges I already have on SO (for example I've earned Citizen Patrol, but there was no notification for this; but when I earned Nice answer there was clear notification for it, since I didn't earn this at SO). Is it the case, or something wrong with me? If it's the case, why?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96951/prevent-the-notification-bar-fiesta/96955#96955 is where the change is mentioned, but I couldn't immediately locate any further posts about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [jonsca mentions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106424/missing-badge-notifications-for-badges-earned-on-other-sites#comment-273301), if you've obtained at least 200 reputation on one or more sites (giving you "veteran" user status), the [notifications you receive are reduced](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96951/prevent-the-notification-bar-fiesta/96955#96955) on associated sites to prevent the notification bar from spamming you about the more trivial badges.

Badges that no longer generate notifications in this case are [most of the bronze badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99082/system-message-indicating-badge-was-awarded-was-not-displayed/99087#99087), notably excluding [tag badges](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges?tab=tags) and post-specific badges such as [Nice Answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/23/nice-answer) or [Nice Question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/20/nice-question).